"Furrr" package R: future_pmap incorrect number of dimensions; Caused by attempted extraction of matrix rows; .l is two variables
I suspect the error is related to my lack of understanding of how to run this function multiple times using future_pmap; as you can see below I designate Ntrials to demonstrate that I desire the function to run 20 times in this particular scenario. Be mindful of the cores you are using if you wish to assist through replication of the code.
library("furrr")
library("parallel")
testmatrix<-matrix(runif((20000*11),-1,21),nrow = 20000, ncol = 11)

Testfunction<-function(ParVp,Ntrials){
  for(simnum in 1:Ntrials){
    #locate parameters for in-host dynamics
    Vp=ParVp[, 1:2]
    tp=ParVp[, 3:4]
    lg=ParVp[, 5:6]
    ld=ParVp[, 7:8]
    Tc=ParVp[, 9:10]
    rho=ParVp[, 11]
    
  print(head(Vp))
  
  }
}
ncores<-detectCores()-2
plan(multisession, workers = ncores)
Testoutput<- future_pmap(list(testmatrix,20),Testfunction)
plan(sequential)

Error in (function (.l, .f, ..., .progress = FALSE)  :
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in ParVp[, 1:2]:
! incorrect number of dimensions

Not sure if it's just a typo, but instead of a list you should pass a list of lists to pmap / future_pmap, try with future_pmap(list(list(testmatrix), list(20)), Testfunction) .   Currently all 20 trials are executed  by a single worker, is this desired behaviour?

Hi margusl! No the desired behaviour is to execute all 20 trials across ncores which in my scenario is 38. In reality it will be 5000 trials.

A function call that you make through future_*() is handled by a single worker, meaning that you most likely want to avoid loops and other iterations in that function.
Start simple. furrr is basically purrr with futures, so it might make sense to step back from parallelism for a moment and get it working with purrr first, picking a purrr tool most suitable for the task at hand.
In your example you have a single matrix and a number of trials, latter can be though of as a sequence of trials, that would be an input for an iterator. And as we only need to iterate over a single sequence, we don't need pmap() here, just map(). As we (presumably) want to get a result for each of our iterations, our function should also return something. Including a 1s delay there so we could easily measure difference between sequential (purrr) and parallel (furrr) execution.
library(purrr)

set.seed(42)
testmatrix <- matrix(runif((20000*11), -1, 21), nrow = 20000, ncol = 11)

Testfunction <- function(trial_n, ParVp = testmatrix) {
  # let's simulate a slowish process, sleep for a ssecond
  Sys.sleep(1)
  # return something
  ParVp[, 1:2] + trial_n * 100 
}

n_trials <- 5
# measuring elapsed time
tictoc::tic("map Testfunction")
Testoutput_1 <- map(1:n_trials, Testfunction)
tictoc::toc()
#> map Testfunction: 5.13 sec elapsed

# check results 
str(Testoutput_1)
#> List of 5
#>  $ : num [1:20000, 1:2] 119 120 105 117 113 ...
#>  $ : num [1:20000, 1:2] 219 220 205 217 213 ...
#>  $ : num [1:20000, 1:2] 319 320 305 317 313 ...
#>  $ : num [1:20000, 1:2] 419 420 405 417 413 ...
#>  $ : num [1:20000, 1:2] 519 520 505 517 513 ...

In 5+ seconds we get a matching lists of results for our input (1:n_trials).
Time to move to furrr:
library(parallel)
library(furrr)

(ncores <- detectCores() - 2)
#> [1] 6
plan(multisession, workers = ncores)

tictoc::tic("future_map Testfunction")
Testoutput_2 <- future_map(1:n_trials, Testfunction)
tictoc::toc()
#> future_map Testfunction: 2.1 sec elapsed

str(Testoutput_2)
#> List of 5
#>  $ : num [1:20000, 1:2] 119 120 105 117 113 ...
#>  $ : num [1:20000, 1:2] 219 220 205 217 213 ...
#>  $ : num [1:20000, 1:2] 319 320 305 317 313 ...
#>  $ : num [1:20000, 1:2] 419 420 405 417 413 ...
#>  $ : num [1:20000, 1:2] 519 520 505 517 513 ...

And we get results from 5 function calls in 2.1s, each taking 1s.

Leave pmap() / furrr_map() for cases where you need to iterate over data.frame rows or do have more than 2 lists / vectors (for 2 there's map2), in latter case you'd pass it a list of lists, something like this
(from ?furrr::future_pmap):
x <- list(1, 10, 100)
y <- list(1, 2, 3)
z <- list(5, 50, 500)

future_pmap(list(x, y, z), my_function_with_3_arguments)

With your current future_pmap(list(testmatrix,20),Testfunction) call, future_pmap tries to iterate over testmatrix values, 220000 scalars; during that first (and failing) iteration, something like this is being evaluated:  Testfunction(testmatrix[1], 20)
If you chose pmap because of "p" like "parallel", the context here is not "parallel execution" but iterating over multiple vectors in parallel, i.e. each iteration gets n-th item from every vector in the input list.
